# How to resue component with different data?

Tags: angular

I have a component that gets input data:

```
@Input() data: any[] = [];
```

The `data` has blocks by type `IBlock {id: number, name: string, values:[] }`

Each block has `values` array with diffrent object properties.

I tried to display block header and values after:

```
Block name
   values of object
```

Problem is that `values` can contain different type object. How to reuse this componen in this case?

Yes, I can pass additinal input paramter as `@Input type: string`. And get properties from `values` based on the type.

Any ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Back-end: If your data can be stored in the database in a way that can better match how the information will be communicated to the user, update your database to better reflect that. If the data cannot be stored differently (for example, 3rd party API), then this isn't an option.
2. Front-end: It's typically best to leave your data as you've received it if you can easily display the information to your users. Only update the data if you're not able to properly show the original data. In this case, you have a clear option to display the information without manipulation the data.

If you can't change how you originally retrieve the data, the first solution of using `*ngIf` to show/hide your information will likely be the best approach.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed my question, but it is useful for me, your answer

Comment: @Den You should not change your question once you have an answer.